# I'm getting the error main.c:20:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: c

I am getting the error main.c:20:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token.  Can anybody Help me with this.  I'm pretty new at c programming and my code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void PrintArray (int number[], int i)
{
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  PrintArray (number, i - 1);
  printf ("Please enter 5 integers:%d\n", i);
  scanf ("%d", &i);
}

int
main ()
{
  int number[5];
  PrintArray (number, 5);
  printf ("Here are your integers:%d", number[4]);
  return 0;
}

{
  int arr[20];
  int l;
  for (l = 0; l < 20; l++)
    {
      arr[l] = rand () % 20;
    }
  for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
    {
      PrintArray (arr, 20);
      printf ("Here are 20 random integers: %d", arr[l]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a stray code block after main

Comment: What is the return and the following `}{` doing in your main?

Comment: In C, code can't exist outside of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this to get rid of the error you quoted.

```
  return 0;
}

{
```

You might also have to move the following variable definitions to the start of main.

I.e. this

```
  int arr[20];
  int l;
```

should go ...

```
int number[5];
/*  ... here */
PrintArray (number, 5);
```

Then check the behaviour of your program; because the previously free-floating code block after your main function is now simply executed after your call to `printf()`. This might not cause the desired behvaviour.

Comment: It was answered in the comments

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Yes, by me (among others at roughly the same time). And I decided to make an answer to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. So wha tis your point?

Comment: As I see the technosaurus was first. And such a trivial error does not deserve the answer

Comment: Yes, by 11 seconds. I.e. I was editing already while his appeared.

Comment: And even if it was by 10 minutes. I am the only one who decided to answer. @PeterJ_01 And being first is not a required attribute for an answer. Just to answer the question in a helpful way.

Comment: A mistake which is considered obvious by experienced programmers like you are might be a problem for a newbie. Espcially in todays world of scripting languages which do not take more than a standalone line of code to be executable. I see that you did not downvote the question, so why consider it so worthless that answering it is forbidden? @PeterJ_01

Comment: @PeterJ_01 This answer doesn't deserved a downvote, specially because it's correct. And let the people decide whether they should write an answer or not. And if you think that a question doesn't deserve an answer, then don't write an answer, just close the tab and ignore the question.

Comment: I was hoping the OP would clarify whether the stray code block was intentional or a pasting error.  It was never intended as an answer as I didn't feel like it was a complete question yet.

Comment: @technosaurus Funny. My comment looks like a question, but then I realised that I more or less meant it to be an answer. I.e. kind of the opposite... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The part of code after main function hasn't a declaration, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void PrintArray (int number[], int i)
{
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  PrintArray (number, i - 1);
  printf ("Please enter 5 integers:%d\n", i);
  scanf ("%d", &i);
}

int
main ()
{
  int number[5];
  PrintArray (number, 5);
  printf ("Here are your integers:%d", number[4]);
  return 0;
}

int print20(void){
  int arr[20];
  int l;
  for (l = 0; l < 20; l++)
    {
      arr[l] = rand () % 20;
    }
  for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
    {
      PrintArray (arr, 20);
      printf ("Here are 20 random integers: %d", arr[l]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```